# Como separar una palabra con jquery y enviar ambas partes a diferentes input text

Tags: jquery

Como se podría separa una palabra ejemplo "SCL-VAP" y luego mostrar "SCL" en un input text y la otra palabra "VAP" mostrarla en otro input text?, considerando que los input text donde se mostraran las palabras estan en una ventana modal?

aquí dejo el codigo html

```
<!DocType:html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<b>Ruta</b><input type="text" value="SCL-VAP" id="ruta">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4">Open Modal</button>

</form>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Formulario</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formulario" method="Post">
          <b>Origen</b><input type="text"  id="ori">
          <b>Destino</b><input type="text"  id="des">

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aca el codigo javascript

```
<script>
var cadena = $("#ruta").val();
separador = "-",
arregloDeSubCadenas = cadena.split(separador);
document.getElementById("ori").value=arregloDeSubCadenas; 

console.log(arregloDeSubCadenas); // la consola devolverá: ["cadena", "de", "texto"]

</script>
```

aca al abrir el modal necesito que la palabra "SCL-VAP" que está en el input id"ruta" que está en la pagina y este se divida en 2 , quedando así "SCL" en un input id="ori" y la otra palabra en el input id"des" cuyos 2 inputs estan en la ventana modal.
por el momento solo puedo ver lo que trae la consola , pero no he podido enviar esos valores por separado y mostrarlos en los input correspondientes.
hay laguna forma?

aqui imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo tienes!! La función de [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) te retorna un arreglo de cadenas.
Ahora, cada parte reprensenta una posicón en el arreglo. Y estos los debes asignar a tus inputs.

```
<script>
var cadena = $("#ruta").val();
separador = "-",
arregloDeSubCadenas = cadena.split(separador);

$("#ori").val(arregloDeSubCadenas[0]);
$("#des").val(arregloDeSubCadenas[1]);

</script>
```

> Para interactuar con un [arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) individualmente, hazlo desde su
>   indice.

Comment: Hola sabes lo acabo de ejecutar y no me funciona, al abrir el modal no se muestran los datos en los input.

Comment: Asegurate de que los ids sean correctos

Comment: si los cambié a id "ori" y id"des" y quite la linea document.getEl..... y nada

Comment: a ahora si , es que estaban pegadas las cookies-, muchas gracias

Comment: oye hola una ultima pregunta, y si el modal donde se mostraran los datos está en otra pagina? como lo hago? porque estando el modal en otra pagina no se muestran los datos en los input.

Comment: Como se podría hacer? habría que indicarle el modal donde están los campos?

Comment: Hay formas de hacerlo en cualquiera de los casos que planteas. Pero decide como lo debes hacer y ¿como lo estás haciendo?. Como es algo diferente sobre esta pergunta, te recomiendo hacer una nueva.